# Twig - Filter date day of week and am/pm

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4

I have a twig template trying to display a `DateTime` property from a doctrine entity.

```
{{ booking.bookingStart|date("d/m/Y") }}
```

This produces the output:

> 17/12/2018

I would like to render the property in two other ways:

1. With 'day of week' name out front:

   > Monday, 17/12/2018
2. Just the time part (`h.m`) with dot between hr and min, and with am or pm:

   > 9.00 am

How can this be done with `date` filter?

Answer (score 2):

you can use all those "format characters" for php´s date 
mentioned [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) :

eg `|date("l, d/m/Y")`